# Python : Remove all data from a column of a dataframe except the last value that we store in the first row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Let's say that I have a simple Dataframe.

```
data1 = [12,34,465,678,896]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns= ['Data'])
print(df1)

   Data
0    12
1    34
2   465
3   678
4   896
```

I want to delete all the data except the last value of the column that I want to save in the first row. It can be an column with thousands of rows. So I would like the result :

```
  Data
0  896
1   
2   
3   
4
```

What are the simplest functions to do that efficiently ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You an use `iloc` where `0` is the first row of the data column, `-1` is the last row and `1:` is every row except the first row:

```
df1['Data'].iloc[0] = df1['Data'].iloc[-1]
df1['Data'].iloc[1:] = ''
df1
Out[1]: 
  Data
0  896
1     
2     
3     
4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `loc` accessor. Utilise the python `x,y=a,b` to assign the values

```
df1.loc[0,'Data'],df1.loc[1::,'Data']=df1['Data'].values[-1],''

 Data
0  896
1     
2     
3     
4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.reverse()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_reverse.asp) method of python lists, something like this:

```
my_data = df1['Data'].to_list() # Get list from Serie
my_data.reverse() # Reverse order.
my_data[1:] = [""]*len(my_data[1:]) # Fill with spaces from the second item.
df1['Data'] = my_data
```

Output:

```
    Data
0   896
1   
2   
3   
4
```